# How to get php 2 dimensional array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery

I am using ajax query from jquery. I have 3 module or 3 file. 1st is php file of represent data , 2nd is js file where all javascipt and ajax code is written and 3rd one is my bussiness logic php file.
              I call a javascript function from my 1st file i.e `show(id)`. After that this function in js file call ajax

```
function show(id){  

    // validation / client side.
    // function - lll to stringmatch - name proper.
    $.ajax({    
        type    : "POST",
        cache   : true,
        dataType: "json",
        url     : "a.php",
        data    : {
                    proid:id
                  },                
        success: function(data) {
         alert(data);
        //$("#match_item_display").html(data);



        }
    });



}
```

and my a.php file return json 2 dimensional array...
After that i want to use json 2 dimmentional array in php or 1st page.

Please help me guys...

Comment: Here is alert data show only [object Object]...so on..

Comment: Provided you wrap that in `$(document).ready()`, it should work fine for you. Can you elaborate on *After that i want to use json 2 dimmentional array in php or 1st page.*?

Comment: my index.php page have html code and php code...i call javascipt function from index page this javascript function on $(document).ready after that call javascipt function its call ajax. This ajax requestion is go on a.php and a.php return 2D array here i use echo json_encode($arr); $arr is 2D array.In ajax success funtion  its return json and i want use this 2d json in index.php...

Comment: Is your problem accessing the array?

Comment: Yes i have json return in data but i want this array in javasciprt..Is this possible..???

Comment: Yes, see my answer below. Without knowing the contents of what you are echoing from the server it's impossible for me to tell you exactly what to write in your callback. But I've given you steps to determine that. Remove alert and use console.log instead. [Open up your web console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525/7961) and analyze the response that is returned from the server. Then drill down into the JavaScript object using the dot (.) operator, accessing the pieces of data you require. If it's an array, consider using a for-in loop

Comment: You can use '.' operator to fetch value. for e.g. data.add Here add is key of array.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data will show as `[object Object]` from an `alert()`.

If you want to analyze the data as it has returned you should log it to the web console with `console.log(data);` instead.

You're then free to use the data in the callback. Provided you returned a json encoded object from PHP, you don't even have to massage the data. Just use `data.prop1`, `data.prop2`... etc

Answer (score 0):

Loop the json array

```
function show(id){  

    // validation / client side.
    // function - lll to stringmatch - name proper.
    $.ajax({    
        type    : "POST",
        cache   : true,
        dataType: "json",
        url     : "a.php",
        data    : {
                    proid:id
                  },                
        success: function(data) {
          var str = '<div><ul>';
         for (i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                  str += '<li>'+data[i]['json_index']+'</li>';
            }
         str +='</ul></div>';




        }
    });



}
```

Comment: how to use this data object on index.php how to implement..please discribe..thanx for suggestion.. :)

Comment: do you want to give the json values to some 'html' elements in the index.php file ?

Comment: Check the update you will have a unordered list having all the elements just put it in your page using jquery like this $('#somecontanerid').html(str);

Answer (score 0):

you cannot view the content of an object or array using alert.
if you use google chrome or firefox with firebug plugins, use `console.log(data);` instead of `alert(data);`

press F12 just before you load the page to enable / show developer toolbar, you should be able to see the object in the console of the firebug or chrome.

good luck.

Comment: I believe F12 is for FF and IE only. See [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525/7961) for details. :)

Comment: Yes, F12 only works in FF (if you have firebug plugins), IE and Chrome.
I've mention FF and Chrome in my answer, but I forgot mentioning IE. Thanks, Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonData = [{"data":"oneone"},{"name":"onetwo"}];
for(var a in jsonData) {
    if(jsonData.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
        for(var b in jsonData[a]) {
            if(jsonData[a].hasOwnProperty(b)) {                                
                alert(jsonData[a][b]);
            }
        }
    }
}
​    ​
```

Comment: Its show undifined my json data is like this var jsonData =
 [{"data":"oneone"},{"data":"onetwo"}]

Comment: var jsonData = [{"data":"oneone"},{"name":"onetwo"}];
alert(jsonData[0].data);

Comment: how to iterate this jsonData on index.php in html code..please explain me... thanx for suggetion.. :)